# Reduce Close Points

Tags: algorithm, matlab

> input: C matrix 2xN (2D points)
>
> output: C matrix 2xM (2D points) with equal or less points.

Lets say we have C matrix 2xN that contains several 2D points, and it looks something like that:

[image]

What we want is to group **"close"** points to one point, measured by the average of the other points.
For example, in the second image, every group of blue circle will be one point, the point coordinate will be the average point off all points in the blue circle.
also by saying **"close"**, I mean that: their distance one to each other will be smaller then `DELTA` (known scalar). So wanted output is:

[image]

About running time of the algorithm, I don't have upper-limit request but I call that method several times...
What i have tried:

```
function C = ReduceClosePoints(C ,l_boundry)
    x_size = abs(l_boundry(1,1)-l_boundry(1,2)); %220
    DELTA = x_size/10;
    T = [];

    for i=1:size(C,2)
        sum = C(:,i);
        n=1;
        for j=1:size(C,2)
            if i~=j     %not in same point
                D = DistancePointToPoint(C(:,i),C(:,j));
                if D < DELTA
                    sum = sum + C(:,j);
                    n=n+1;
                end
            end
        end
        sum = sum./n; %new point -> save in T matrix
        T = [T sum];
    end
    C = T;
end
```

I am using Matlab.
Thank you

Comment: Please provide what you have tried.

Comment: The code you've posted works fine for me - what exactly is the question here?

Comment: Hi Notlikethat, thank you for your help! lets think about the next input for C Matrix. C = [0 1 1.5 50 51 ; 0 1 1.5 50 51]; and lets think about DELTA = 10; as it expected by the points value and DELTA value, we want to see only two points in the result output. but i dont get the wanted result.

Comment: @MatanTouti Ah, my bad, I was plotting the points rather than looking at the matrices so I didn't notice the duplicates in the output.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to remove the duplicates from the output is in the final step, by replacing:

```
C = T;
```

with:

```
C = unique(T', 'rows')';
```

Note that `unique()` in matrix context only works row-wise, so we have to transpose twice.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to remove points that i have tested before.
If that code will be useful to someone use that code:

```
function C = ReduceClosePoints(C ,l_boundry)
     x_size = abs(boundry(1,1)-boundry(1,2)); %220 / 190
     DELTA = x_size/10;
     i=1;
     while i~=size(C,2)+1
         sum = C(:,i);
         n=1;
         j=i;
         while j~=size(C,2)+1
             if i~=j     %not same point
                 D = DistancePointToPoint(C(:,i),C(:,j));
                 if D < DELTA
                     sum = sum + C(:,j);
                     n=n+1;
                     C(:,j) = [];
                     j=j-1;
                 end
             end
             j=j+1;
         end
         C(:,i) = sum./n; %change to new point
         i=i+1;
     end
end
```